# SQL Query about checking a column value if it equals a given value then do something

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a table named `FullSchedule` and it contains teachers names and days and times within each day, and i want to write a Query as the following question

select all fields from `FullSchedule`, if the teacher's name = 'SomeName' then add a column called `Check` with the value 'Found' else if not found put the value 'Not Found'

what is the correct Query for this question ? notice that the teacher's column contains different names but i want to check for one of them. simply making a schedule for each teacher.

Answer (score 0):

I would have that column in my table with a predefined value, let's say it's 'Not found' or 'Not checked' and then I would set that variable with a query of the type:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column1 = value1, column2 = value2...., columnN = valueN
WHERE [condition];
```

If that doesn't fit your needs, you can try a set query from a query or something like this